# Cypress is ignoring exceptions and stop execution inspite of declairing "Cypress.on("uncaught:exception", (err, runnable) => { return false; });"

Tags: cypress

I am trying to use Cypress.io for automating salesforce application.
While trying to automate creating some entity in Salesforce my underline application is throwing some error. I want to ignore these uncaught exceptions and continue. I have already added following code in command.js and importing command.js in index.js

```
Cypress.on("uncaught:exception", (err, runnable) => {
  return false;
});
```

However during execution, Cypress is returning true and doesn't continue with execution.